# SQLserver query result output to Hive without worrying about columns names

Tags: sql-server, hive, sqoop

I have a pretty complex SQL server query to return a report. I want to move the result table to Hive.

I know that [SQOOP has free-form query](http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh/3/sqoop/SqoopUserGuide.html#_free_form_query_imports) function built in. However, it clearly says that

> "The facility of using free-form query in the current version of Sqoop
>   is limited to simple queries where there are no ambiguous projections
>   and no OR conditions in the WHERE clause. Use of complex queries such
>   as queries that have sub-queries or joins leading to ambiguous
>   projections can lead to unexpected results."

So I guess the --query feature won't work in this case and I have to move the related tables from sql server to hive/hdfs, then rewrite the query into a HQL flavor query.

So here is where the headache goes to:
SQLserver has pretty low restriction on the table/column name.. you can put space and other characters in there and you just need to put square brackets around it [] and it will work. For example, [Company Name].[Column Name], I don't think HIVE is so "flexible".

Does that mean:

(1) When I move the table from SQLserver to Hive, I need to do a free-form query to manually change all the columns to a legit name, something like

> /usr/bin/sqoop import --driver 'net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver' --connect 'jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://xxxx' --query 'SELECT "No_" as "No_", "ECCN_HTS Hold" as "ECCN_HTS_Hold", "Vendor Site Name" as
>   "Vendor_Site_Name" from [company$Sales Line] WHERE $CONDITIONS'
>   --target-dir /directoary/data/data_sales_line -m 1 --fields-terminated-by '\001' --append

(2) After that, do you have to manually create a hive external table pointing to the hdfs directory?

I gonna say I have so many columns in my table and I guess this is really not the way that it suppose to work, can anyone point me to the right direction? Some examples and move table into hive without worrying about the column name will be very much appreciated!

Comment: Wait why do you column names have spaces in them in SQLServer? Just because it can be done doesn't mean it should be done.

Comment: @Zane I cannot agree with you more. I am not the creator of those tables and right now, it is the way it is as production